# what is best way to accept function input parameters in php?

Tags: php, function, input, parameters

I am writing a program and need to choose whether to use arrays or variables as input for functions, so generally speaking what are the pros and cons of accepting function input parameters in the following ways.

**using variables**

```
function (p1=v1,p2=v2)
```

**using arrays**

```
$config = array(){
p1=>v1
p2=>v2
}

function ($config)
```

for example
some of the pros of the using variables is for the generating php documentations and the ability to set default parameters. On the other hand the code can get quite messy for a long parameter list.

some of the pros of the using arrays is the easy of passing same values if more than one function needs the same input and it is also easier to read.

what else?

Comment: This is way too broad. You can check current projects and their standards as well read up on Clean Code

Comment: As you already said, both ways have their pros and cons. And because you already know this pros and cons its now up to you to decide what is the best for your project.

Comment: This would be completely up to you and your opinion. There is no good answer as they both work.

Comment: Also, I would argue that passing in an array is not easier to read. While that one function call might be easier,  if the array is defined elsewhere, you are essentially passing in what amounts to magic (an unknown value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You summarize the pros and cons pretty well, so maybe you should consider a combination of both? Having overloaded functions that take some default parameters (if you want them) and then having a function that also takes an array of information as its last argument, if you need extra information.
It's a bit more work to program, but it also is a good compromise that will make the code more flexible in the future.